# Displaying data from database in JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to display data in JSP and i am wondering if there is a better way then what i have done. I am not really experienced in Java or JSP so the code i made is probably not the cleanest.

I will only be returning count from my database as shown below so i will not be returning huge amounts of data i just need the number of rows from the database to display in my divs.

Would appreciate any help if anyone has any ideas but functionally what i have at the moment works good and without any problems i am just worried about security and how messy the code is.

My project is making Wallboard for my company that displays number if insurances concluded that day.I am using Hibernate framework and Reveal js for this project and i will not be using Servlet for displaying data so that is why i am calling `data.jsp` in ajax call.

index.jsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Service.PolicaService" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Config.*" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.DAO.PolicaDAO2" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.DAO.PolicaDaoInterface" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Entity.Polica" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <title>reveal.js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/black.css">-->
        
        
        <!-- Theme used for syntax highlighted code
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin/highlight/monokai.css"> -->
        
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Moji dodatki-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/v-charts/lib/index.min.js"></script>
        
         
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                            
                <!--PAGE 2-->
                <section class = "slide2" data-background-image="slike/slide2.jpg">
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="slide2_body">
                        <div class="row justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 slide2_right">
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                <h3 class="h3_light">Danes smo zavarovali</h3>
                                <div class="result">
                                    
                                </div>
                                    <h3 class="h3_light">vozil</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <hr class="line_light">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                    <h3 class="h3_light">Skupaj je zavarovanih že</h3>

                                    <div class="result">
                                        <!-- THIS IS WHERE I DISPLAY COUNT FROM DATABASE -->
                                    </div>

                                    <h3 class="h3_light">vozil</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </section>                  
                                
            </div>
        </div>
        
         
        <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/highlight/highlight.js"></script>
        <script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/chart.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="plugin/chart/plugin.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            // More info about initialization & config:
            // - https://revealjs.com/initialization/
            // - https://revealjs.com/config/
            Reveal.initialize({
                hash: true,
                //autoSlide: 5000,
                //loop: true,
                slideNumber: true,
                disableLayout: true, 
                center: true,
                controls: true,
                progress: true, 

                plugins: [ RevealMarkdown, RevealHighlight, RevealNotes, RevealChart ]
            });
            
            Reveal.on( 'slidechanged', event => {
                
                currentSlide = Reveal.getCurrentSlide()

                page = Reveal.getIndices(slide=currentSlide);
                h = Object.values(page)[0];
                console.log(stran);
                console.log(test);
                
                if(h == 0) {
                    Stran1();
                }
                if(h == 1) {
                    refresh();
                }
            });
            
            
            //ajax
            
            function refresh() {
                
                 $.ajax({
                        url: "data.jsp",
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(res) {
                            
                            $('.result').html(res);
                        }
                    });
                
            }
                                
        
        </script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

My PolicaDAO2 class:

```
package digiwallboard.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import digiwallboard.Entity.Polica;

public class PolicaDAO2 implements PolicaDaoInterface<Polica, String> {
    
    private Session currentSession;
    
    private Transaction currentTransaction;
 
    public PolicaDAO2() {
        
    }
 
    public Session openCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }
 
    public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }
     
    public void closeCurrentSession() {
        currentSession.close();
    }
     
    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }
     
    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Polica.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;
    }
 
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }
 
    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }
 
    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return currentTransaction;
    }
 
    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
        this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
    }
 
      
   
    public List<Polica> findAll() {
        
        Session session = openCurrentSession();
                
        
        Query<Polica> result = session.createQuery("FROM Polica", Polica.class);
        
        List<Polica> result2 = result.getResultList();
        
        closeCurrentSession();
    
        
        
        return result2;
                
    }
    
    public Long findCount() {
        
        Session session = openCurrentSession();
        
        //TypedQuery result = openCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Polica", Polica.class);
        //Long count = (Long)result.getSingleResult();
        
        Query result = session.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Polica", Polica.class);
        Long count = (Long)result.uniqueResult();
        
        return count;
        
    }
}
```

PolicaDaoInterface

```
 package digiwallboard.DAO;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface PolicaDaoInterface<T, Id extends Serializable> {
    
    public List<T> findAll();

    public Long findCount();

}
```

PolicaService

```
package digiwallboard.Service;

import java.util.List;

import digiwallboard.DAO.PolicaDAO2;
import digiwallboard.Entity.Polica;

public class PolicaService {

    private static PolicaDAO2 policaDao;
    
    public PolicaService() {
        policaDao = new PolicaDAO2();
    }
    
    public List<Polica> findAll() {
        policaDao.openCurrentSession();
        List<Polica> police = policaDao.findAll();
        policaDao.closeCurrentSession();
        return police;
    }
        
    public static Long findCount() {
        policaDao.openCurrentSession();
        Long police = policaDao.findCount();
        policaDao.closeCurrentSession();
        return police;
    }
    
}
```

`data.jsp` this is where i display count from database currently there is only 1 count here but there will be multiple here so i am wondering also if there is a way to call specific one using ajax.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Service.PolicaService" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Config.*" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.DAO.PolicaDAO2" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.DAO.PolicaDaoInterface" %>
<%@page import="digiwallboard.Entity.Polica" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <p><%=PolicaService.findCount() %></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And finally my ajax call:

```
function refresh() {
 $.ajax({
        url: "data.jsp",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            
            $('.result').html(res);
        }
    });
}
```